# Are there any published travel guides for GA Pilots?

Tags: aviation-history, general-aviation

Are there any published travel guides for GA Pilots specific to the US? Kind of like Michelin Guides, except for airplanes instead of cars and highlight scenic, historic or notable routes?

Comment: Baja Bush Pilots has guides for Mexico and Central America https://www.bushpilotsinternational.com/bpi_store/product_categories.php?category=2

Comment: This seems like a very broad question. Are you asking about a specific country or region? Even then, we typically don’t answer questions about information sources, because they can change frequently. If you’re asking about the US, you could start with [AOPA’s travel page](https://www.aopa.org/travel).

Answer (score 2):

[Wisconsin publishes one](https://wisconsindot.gov/Pages/travel/air/airport-info/arptdir-city.aspx) and even has a ForeFlight content pack. Other states may publish similar guides.